# Sed to extract till first space after 2nd word

Tags: shell, sed, awk

How can we use sed to get the 4 characters between "`Install ID:`" and first space after `XKCD`, basically I want to extract "`XKCD`" string out of it

```
Install ID:          XKCD (8426200,8179503)
```

I tried using -

```
 echo "Install ID:          XKCD (8426200,8179503)" | sed -n 's/^.*ID:\(.*\)*$/\1/p'
```

but that gives me "`XKCD (8426200,8179503)`" instead of just `XKCD`. I am not able to figure out, how to hand the space part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of minor revisions to your attempt:

```
echo "Install ID:          XKCD (8426200,8179503)" | sed -n 's/^.*ID: *\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/p'
```

or

```
echo "Install ID:          XKCD (8426200,8179503)" | awk '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 test="Install ID:          XKCD (8426200,8179503)"
 echo $test | sed -re 's/^.*\:\s+([A-z]{4}).*/\1/'
```

Or: ignore everything before the colon, ignore spaces after the colon, get the four chars after the spaces, then ignore everything afterwards. If your characters include numbers or other things it would currently fail, though (you'd need to add them to the list in the square brackets).

Comment: Thanks!!
I tried doing - sed -n 's/^.*ID: *\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/p'
but I am getting "sed: -e expression #1, char 24: Invalid range end"

Comment: The -re puts sed in extended regular expression mode (not available on some systems, though hopefully it is on yours). Very useful when it is available...

Comment: Note that the `-r` option for sed will only work in Linux (GNU sed) and recent versions of FreeBSD or NetBSD.  In older *BSD or OSX, you need to use the `-E` option to get the same effect.  Extended RE is not available in the sed that ships with any SVR4 unix that I know of (though I'd love to hear corrections on that point).